# Declaring the " i " variable outside the for statement of for loop will speed up the execution of the loop, what is the reason of that?

Tags: javascript, performance, for-loop

I think declaring the variable i inside for statement will execute just once,and in the next iteration, the i variable will increment by one and compare with the arr.length regardless the first argument in the for statement,
i mean, in this way we make the declaring outside the (for statement) in order to not doing it by the loop, Note that this step will be ignored by the loop at every iteration 
so, how does this behavior be able to speed up the execution of for loop?

```
var i;
var l = arr.length;
for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaring `i` with `var` outside the loop will not affect the performance due to [variable hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting) in JS.

However, attributing the array length in the variable `l` does speed the performance, compared to `for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {`, because there is no need to access the `length` property each loop turn.

**NOTE** that you can also use this syntax, as the first part of `for` declaration is executed only once: `for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {`

**ALSO** I personnally prefer to declare it outside the loop because people that don't know very well JS could believe that the `var` is scoped to the `for` loop, which is not the case (compared to `let`). See also CertainPerformance's comment.

Comment: Though. using `var` instead of `let` for `i` may well result in a (near insignificant) difference due to the different variable binding.